# Spinner doesn't work setOnItemSelectedListener

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

`Onitemselectedlistener` does not work when I select data in `spinner`. I am not sure what's up?

The data I choose is unreadable. How can I read the data I chose in `spinner`? This version of the code does not work, the selected data does not appear.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnTouchListener {
    private Spinner spinner;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMain);
        ArrayAdapter < String > adapterSpinner = new ArrayAdapter < String > (MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Rooms);
        adapterSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapterSpinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);
        adapterSpinner.notifyDataSetChanged();

        final AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView < ? > adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView < ? > adapterView) {

            }
        };

        final Spinner spnLocale = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMain);

        spnLocale.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView < ? > adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                spnLocale.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView < ? > adapterView) {
                return;
            }
        });
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: why are you using `spnLocale.setOnItemSelectedListener` two times?

Comment: It doesn't work once I use it.

Comment: you have two spinners right?

Comment: are you talking about the `spnLocale` or `spinner` in the question ?

Comment: Try my answer and check plesse

Answer (score 0):

You have already taken the global spinner at the top.  Implement listener for that like this -

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new 
 AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);

                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                    return;
                }
            });
```